# Password protected directory now I can't access it

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I use Godaddy for hosting a Wordpress site and I just went into Cpanel and password protected a directory I made. But instead of asking for a password I get the Wordpress 404 not found error. I went back into Cpanel and removed the password protection and now I still get the not found error.

How can I get things back to normal again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you should go to your website root and delete .htpasswd file from it. also you may remove AuthType commands from .htaccess file.